# react: повторный вызов диалога через изменение состояния

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap, state, setstate

У меня есть выпадающий список и диалог, который отображается при выборе определённого элемента выпадающего списка

Реализовано это следующим образом (выкинул все, чтобы не мешало смотреть):

```
// функция срабатывающая при выборе элемента в выпадающем списке
handleSelect = (eventKey: any, event: any) => {

    this.setState({
        selected_id:        eventKey,
        is_activated:       event.target.classList.contains('dialogselected')
    });
}

// отобразить выпадающий список и диалог
return (
    <>
        <Dropdown>
            <Dropdown.Menu>
                <Dropdown.Item 
                    onSelect = {this.handleSelect}
                >...</Dropdown.Item>
            </Dropdown.Menu>
        </Dropdown>
        {this.state.is_activated ? <MyDialog /> : null}
    </>
);
```

Когда выбирается элемент с классом `dialogselected` отображается диалог.

Если диалог закрыть и еще раз выбрать этот же самый элемент списка, то диалог не отобразится повторно **потому что состояние не изменилось**, т.е. `is_activated` как был `true` так и остался.

Подскажите как можно корректно исправить данную ситуацию?

Т.е. требуется, чтобы диалог вызывался повторно, т.е. надо как-то дать понять reactу, что состояние дернули

Comment: При закрытии диалога устанавливать `is_activated` в  `false` ? Не вижу кода как диалог закрывается

Answer (score 0):

нашел решение

1. в диалог в качестве параметров передается колбек onClose

   ```
    {this.state.is_activated ? <MyDialog onClose = {this.handleClose} /> : null}
   ```
2. диалог при закрытии вызывает полученный колбек
3. компонент из которого был вызван диалог в данном колбеке скидывает `is_activated` в `false`

   ```
    handleClose = () => {
        this.setState({
            is_activated:       false
        });
    }
   ```

после этого проблема была решена